# Permanent ConnectionClosed exception in Haskell's websockets client

Tags: haskell, websocket

I need to receive notifications from [Aria2 Downloader](http://aria2.github.io). It used WebSocket for notifications posting, so I am trying to receive them with [websockets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets) library. The code is short and simple:

```hs
import qualified Network.WebSockets as WSC
import qualified Network.Socket as SC
import Control.Exception.Safe
...

recvThr :: MyState -> WSC.Connection -> IO ()
recvThr st conn = forever $ body `catch` onError
    where
        onError (x::SomeException) = do
            ...
            threadDelay 1000000

        body = do
            -- expected message is:
            -- '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"aria2.onDownloadStart","params":[{"gid":"287834a3deb0eb68"}]}'
            msg <- WSC.receiveDataMessage conn
            print msg
            threadDelay 1000 -- without it the problem is the same


myFork :: MyState -> IO ()
myFork st = do
    SC.withSocketsDo $ WSC.runClient "localhost" 6800 "/jsonrpc" p
    where p conn = void $ forkIO $ recvThr st conn
```

I run aria2c on the localhost. The default port is 6800 and the path is "/jsonrpc". The configuration of the aria2 is:

```
dir=/downloads
continue
log-level=debug
log=/downloads/aria2.log
allow-overwrite=true
daemon=true
max-connection-per-server=10
max-concurrent-downloads=20
max-overall-download-limit=0
min-split-size=25M
enable-http-pipelining=true
enable-rpc=true
rpc-listen-all=true
rpc-secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But this Haskell code does not work: I get `ConnectionClosed` exception immediately - on `receiveDataMessage`. If I replace it with `sendTextData` or even `sendClose` - then I get the same exception on them. So, I suppose it maybe because of either: 1) Connection object is really closed, 2) timeout happens.

How to fix it?

I tried to test the notifications receiving through WebSocket with Python, and the result was:

- I need only 2 calls: `create_connection()` and `recv()` on the socket (no any sends, authentications, nothing more, just these 2 calls)
- It works on the address `ws://localhost:6800/jsonrpc` and I get notifications
- Initially I've got timeout exception in the `recv()` so I passed a big timeout value to the `create_connection(..., timeout=...)` call then `recv()` waits for notification with this big timeout.

What is the problem with the Haskell code? How to fix it? I suppose more probably reason is a timeout, but I don't see a way how to set the timeout value. A typical handling of the timeout in the Python's [aria2p library](https://github.com/pawamoy/aria2p/blob/master/src/aria2p/client.py) is a receiving (call of `socker.recv()`) in the loop. But my code does the same: `body` works in the loop, but I get the `ConnectionClosed` exception permanently! Another possible reason is that the library does not perform correct connection. I tried to stop the aria2 service, but in the case I get another error ("connection refused") which means: 1) it's correct; 2) the problem is not in the TCP connection to aria2. Any hints are very helpful.